# connecting to FTP server - The remote server returned an error: (550)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, .net-4.0, ftp

I'm getting the error "*The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).*" when I call my function sendFile2FTP

```
    Function sendFile2FTP(fileNameLocal As String, fileNameServer As String, user As String, password As String) As String


        Dim ftpRequest As Net.FtpWebRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create(fileNameServer)
        ftpRequest.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(user, password)
        ftpRequest.Method = Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile
        Try
            Dim ficheiro() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileNameLocal)
            Dim ftpStream As System.IO.Stream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream()
            ftpStream.Write(ficheiro, 0, ficheiro.Length)
            ftpStream.Close()
            ftpStream.Dispose()

            Return "True"
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ex.Message

        End Try

  End Function
```

And this are the parameters that i'm sending to the function (which are all valid)

> fileNameLocal -> C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AgenteExportDebitosCC\AgenteExportDebitosCC\bin\Debug\file02-05-2014.xml
>
> fileNameServer -> ftp://ftp.server.com/intranet/file02-05-2014.xml
>   user -> user
>
> password ->password

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

I'm not sure if this is a permission issue, but I am able to create files with filezilla using the same credentials...

Comment: Check the remote path you're sending and that you really have write permissions on the server side. Is your fileNameServer parameter really the whole string `ftp://ftp.server.com/intranet/file02-05-2014.xml`?

Comment: I've just edited the post right before your question. I am able to create files using Filezilla. According to filezilla, the permission set to that particular folder is "777".

The file name is a concatenation of the full path of the ftp folder, which is stored in the "<app>.exe.config", and the file name (that exists in the local storage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was regarding the ftp address. Instead of

> ftp://ftp.server.com/intranet/file02-05-2014.xml

I had to use the username in the address

> ftp://username@ftp.server.com/server.com/intranet/file02-05-2014.xml