# System.net.webexception. The remote server returned an error: (530) not logged in

Tags: vb.net, error-handling, vb.net-2010

I am trying to get the date/time stamp of the file from the FTP server and doing that it's giving me an error that the remote server needs to be logged in. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I am coding in vb.net in visual studio and here is  my code :

```
  Dim ftp As Net.FtpWebRequest =  Net.FtpWebRequest.Create(URI)
  request.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password) 'Here is the login
  ftp.Method = Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetDateTimestamp
  Dim dte As DateTime
  Using response = CType(ftp.GetResponse(), Net.FtpWebResponse)
      dte = response.LastModified
  End Using
```

Comment: Perhaps you should pass [**credentials**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.credentials(v=vs.110).aspx) along with the request and actually log in?

Comment: I tried it's not working. Can you show me how?

Comment: Show me your attempt instead (remove the actual credentials of course) and I can tell you if you're doing something wrong. Update your question with the new code.

Comment: Seems about right, but don't you mean `ftp.Credentials` rather than `request.Credentials`? Also, where is this server hosted? Perhaps you need to specify the username in the URL/URI as well? I.e: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23469884

Comment: Thankyou it worked i changed from request to ftp.credentials

Comment: Keep track of your variables ;). Glad I could help! I voted to close this as caused by a typographical error. If you'd like to close this right away you can do so by pressing the `close` button underneath your question and selecting `off-topic because...` and then `This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error (...)`